# This condition will always return 'false' since the types '"development" | "production" | "test"' and '"local"' have no overlap.ts(2367)

Tags: typescript, create-react-app

I'm trying to do this

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "local") {
  links = [authLink, apolloLogger, uploadLink];
}
```

But am getting this

```
(property) NodeJS.ProcessEnv.NODE_ENV: "development" | "production" | "test"
This condition will always return 'false' since the types '"development" | "production" | "test"' and '"local"' have no overlap.ts(2367)
```

This works fine in JS. The NODE_END is a string.

Oddly (I'm using create-react-app) if I use this, it works

```
REACT_APP_NODE_ENV=local
```

```
if (process.env.REACT_APP_NODE_ENV === "local") {
  links = [authLink, apolloLogger, uploadLink];
}
```

Comment: Ah... just reread the error I see now.

Answer (score 0):

to check for the local env it should be

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  links = [authLink, apolloLogger, uploadLink];
}
```

The same is pointed out in the error that there are ENVs `"development" | "production" | "test"` but you are trying to compare it with value `local` which does not exists and hence this will always return false.

You see the error says `no overlap`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to manually override `process.env.NODE_ENV` and that's something CRA doesn't support.

Check this documentation to add Custom Environment Variables when using CRA
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/